# Can we get a tag for the Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just edited the tags of [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13763/is-this-a-correct-understanding-of-tsiolkovskys-rocket-equation/13766#13767). I'm surprised we don't have a tag for the Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation. Shouldn't we have one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, I don't see why not, so I added [rocket-equation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocket-equation) to the question, creating a new tag. I also [added a synonym](https://space.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) [tsiolkovsky-rocket-equation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsiolkovsky-rocket-equation) to it. Note that you can also [create new tags](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) yourself by simply typing it in the list of tags when editing or asking a new question, and is one of the [site privileges](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) granted to members during beta when reaching 150 site reputation points. And you should soon reach the [next privilege at 1,250 points](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) to also suggest tag synonyms yourself.